# qt, signal slots not connecting?

Tags: c++, qt, signals

I have a qdialog, with a buttonbox at the bottom; Why isn't this slot not getting fired when a "signal" occurs? The code look like the following:

```
    std::unique_ptr<MW::GenStd> box(new MW::GenStd(&tOut, &tIn));
    box->ui.ChoiceButtons->addButton ("Ask",
        QDialogButtonBox::AcceptRole );
    box->ui.ChoiceButtons->addButton ("OverWrite",
        QDialogButtonBox::AcceptRole );
    box->ui.ChoiceButtons->addButton ("merge",
        QDialogButtonBox::AcceptRole );
    box->ui.ChoiceButtons->addButton ("Skip",
        QDialogButtonBox::RejectRole );

    QObject::connect(box->ui.ChoiceButtons, SIGNAL(clicked(QPushButton* b)), box.get(), SLOT(OnClick(QPushButton* b)));

    return box->exec();
```

Where MW::GenStd is a dialog box (and ui.ChoicButtons a buttonbox). The modal dialog is correctly displayed - however it doesn't seem to interact at all.. Pressing the buttons doesn't fire the event. The slot is declared like the following:

```
public slots:
    void OnClick(QPushButton* b) {
        auto s(b->text());
        if (s == "Merge") {
            setResult(2);
        } else if (s == "Overwrite") {
            setResult(1);
        } else if (s == "Skip") {
            setResult(0);
        } else if (s == "Ask") {
            setResult(3);
        }
    }

};
```

(I know it's terribly to do such a string comparison here, but it's just as a quick mock up test to validate the buttons). But debugging shows the function isn't ever reached!

EDIT: as suggested looking at the output showed a culprit:
`Object::connect: No such signal QDialogButtonBox::clicked(QPushButton*) in AskGUISupport.cpp:150`
However that seems totally strange as the QDialogButtonBox does have a clicked signal? [documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdialogbuttonbox.html#clicked)

Comment: What is the type of `ChoiceButtons`? Also, when connection failed, `Qt` prints warning to console/debugger, that will be extremely useful.

Comment: @Lol4t0: well this error pops up `Object::connect: No such signal QDialogButtonBox::clicked(QPushButton*) in AskGUISupport.cpp:150` - But the qt manually really states clicked is a signal?

Comment: Why are you not connecting QPushButton clicked() signals directly to your slots? You cannot define your own custom signal for a ButtonBox class (Is this a Qt widget class?) and expect the event loop to know this signal and fire it automagically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QDialogButtonBox has a signal `clicked ( QAbstractButton * button )` so you need to define a slot `void OnClick(QAbstractButton* b)` and connect to it. Use QAbstractButton, not QPushButton.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use variable names in connect:

```
QObject::connect(box->ui.ChoiceButtons, SIGNAL(clicked(QPushButton*)), 
                 box.get(), SLOT(OnClick(QPushButton*)));
```

Answer (score 0):

`QDialogButtonBox` class does not has signal

`clicked(QPushButton*)`.

It has [`clicked ( QAbstractButton*)`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdialogbuttonbox.html#clicked) insted.

You should be very precise in signatures, when using signals/slots mechanisms. Any casts not allowed, because `Qt` uses strings internally to check signatures.

You should use `clicked (QAbstractButton*)` signature and adjust your slot to accpet `QAbstractButton*`. Make a slot

```
void OnClick(QAbstractButton* b);
```